# Get keys from dictionary, nested dictionary, lists and check how many times it appears

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

So basically, I am trying to write a code that takes a dictionary from a json file. The dictionary contain other dictionaries, lists, etc...
I am trying to get all the keys from json(results,x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,a1,b1) and show how many time each key appears while checking the nested dictionaries and lists.

Code:

```
# open data
import json

with open('list.json') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)

k=int()

def count_k_v(k):
        keys=0
        if type(k)==dict:
            for value in k.keys():
                if isinstance(k[value], (dict,list)):
                    keys+=1
                    k=count_k_v(k[value])
                    keys+=k
                else:
                    keys+=1
        elif type(k)==list:
            for value in k:
                if isinstance(value,(list,dict)):
                    k=count_k_v(value)
                    keys+=k
                else:
                    keys+=1
        return keys


#['results','x1','x2','y1','x3','y2','a1','b1']     
for key, value in my_dict:
    print("{}".format(key,value))   

#FOUND 8 KEYS.
print("Found {} keys.",count_k_v(my_dict))

#RESULTS FOUND 1 TIME
#X1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
#X2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
#Y1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
#X3 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
#Y2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
#A1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
#B1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
for key in my_dict:
```

JSON:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "x1":5
      },
      {
         "x2":5,
         "y1":[
            1,
            2,
            3
         ]
      },
      {
         "x3":5,
         "y2":{
            "a1":2,
            "b1":67
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Trying to get printed:

```
['results','x1','x2','y1','x3','y2','a1','b1']
FOUND 8 KEYS.
RESULTS FOUND 1 TIME
X1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
Y1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X3 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
Y2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
A1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
B1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive approach, with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def get_result(d):
    keys = []

    def recurse(d):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for k, v in d.items():
                keys.append(k)
                if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                    recurse(v)

        elif isinstance(d, list):
            for item in d:
                if isinstance(item, (dict, list)):
                    recurse(item)
        else:
            return
    recurse(d)
    print(keys)
    print(f'found {len(keys)} keys.'.upper())
    for k, v in Counter(keys).items():
        print(f'{k} key found {v} time'.upper())

get_result(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
['results', 'x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'x3', 'y2', 'a1', 'b1']
FOUND 8 KEYS.
RESULTS KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
Y1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X3 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
Y2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
A1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
B1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
```

Or, you can just parse the `json string` with `re` [ *not full-proof, recommended for simple json* ]:

```
import re

def get_result(json_str):
    keys = re.findall(r'"([^"]+?)"\s*:', json_str)
    print(keys)
    print(f'found {len(keys)} keys'.upper())
    for k, v in Counter(keys).items():
        print(f'{k} key found {v} time'.upper())

print(get_result(json.dumps(my_dict)))
```

Output:

```
['results', 'x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'x3', 'y2', 'a1', 'b1']
FOUND 8 KEYS.
RESULTS KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
Y1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
X3 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
Y2 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
A1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
B1 KEY FOUND 1 TIME
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I am going to check the recursive function.